# Unsure how to solve this integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, curves

Let $$F\left(x,y\right)=xi+e^{y^2}j.$$ Evaluate $$\int _CF\cdot dr,$$ where $C$ is the curve $$r\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{t^2+1}i+\left(3+10t^2\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)\right)j,\quad0\le t\le 1.$$

I am having a bit of difficulty with this as I have already tried setting it up as $$\int _0^1F\left(r\left(t\right)\right)\cdot r'\left(t\right)dt.$$ But I get really large equations for the derivative of $r(t)$ which leads to math that I just can't do on paper. I think I can use greens theorem but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: Green's theorem would be a good idea, but it would only work for a closed curve, which isn't what we have here. Instead, have you considered the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integration?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to apply that theorem to this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem? If so, can you make your vector field $F$ meet its hypotheses?

Comment: No I'm not that familiar with the theorem, can you write it out or send a link that explains it.

Comment: [Here you are](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/fundthmlineintegrals.aspx), the major statement is $\int_C \nabla f \cdot d\vec r = f(\vec r(b)) - f(\vec r(a)).$ Basically, a line-integral version of the FTC

Comment: So would $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{1^2+1}&e^{\left(3+10\left(1\right)^2cos\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\right)^2}\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{0^2+1}&e^{\left(3+10\left(0\right)^2cos\left(\frac{\pi \cdot 0}{2}\right)\right)^2}\end{pmatrix}$$ be the correct way to apply the theorem?

Comment: Not quite: start by checking if your field is conservative. If so, try to find its potential (the function that it is the gradient of) and then evaluate that potential at the two endpoints

Comment: I'm still having a bit of difficulty as when I try to get the potential function of F, I keep ending up with 0 (The derivative of x^2/2+C with respect to y just gives 0).

Comment: When you integrate a partial derivative, instead of using a constant you use a function of the other variables: so you should instead have $\frac12 x^2 + C(y),$ since that $C(y)$ is what would vanish when taking a partial derivative with respect to $x.$ Then taking partials with respect to $y$ would give you $C'(y) = e^{y^2}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following fact:

> *Theorem:* Let $F=P\vec{i}+Q\vec{j}$ be a vector field over a *region simply connected* $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Suppose that $P,Q\in \mathcal{C}^{1}(\Omega)$ and $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y)$$
> for all $(x,y)\in \Omega$. Therefore $F$ is a conservative vector field and thus there exists a potential function $f$ such that $\nabla f=F$.

Define $P(x,y)=x$ and $Q(x,y)=e^{y^{2}}$ and notice that $$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x,y)=0=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}(x,y)$$
for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ so $F(x,y)=P(x,y)\vec{i}+Q(x,y)\vec{j}$ is a conservative vector field by the *theorem*.

Thus, there exists a function $f$ such that $\nabla f=F$.

Since $f$ there exists and satisfies $\nabla f=F$ so
$$f_{x}(x,y)=x,\quad f_{y}(x,y)=e^{y^{2}}$$
then integrating $f_{x}(x,y)=x$ respect to $x$ we have $f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+g(y)$ and then differentiating respect to $y$ we have $f_{y}(x,y)=g'(y)$ but also $f_{y}(x,y)=e^{y^{2}}$ so $g'(y)=e^{y^{2}}$ and integrating respect to $y$ we have $g(y)=\int e^{y^{2}}\, {\rm d}y$. Thus,
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\int_{0}^{y} e^{s^{2}}\, {\rm d}s$$
Notice that indeed $\nabla f=F$.

Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integration
\begin{align*}\int_{C}F\cdot\, {\rm d}r&=f(r(1))-f(r(0))\\&=f\left(\frac{1}{2},3\right)-f\left(1,3\right)\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}{2}+\int_{0}^{3}e^{s^{2}}\, {\rm d}s-\frac{1^{2}}{2}-\int_{0}^{3}e^{s^{2}}\, {\rm d}s,\\ &=\frac{1}{2^{3}}-\frac{1}{2},\\&=\boxed{-\frac{3}{8}}\end{align*}